# AVR PROGMEM reads garbage instead of string

Tags: c, gcc, arduino, avr, avr-gcc

I have some problem with reading string from program memory:

```
const char str[] PROGMEM = "Test string here\r\n";
```

Here are my printing routines:

```
/** Send string over UART */
void uart_puts(char* str)
{
    while (*str) {
        uart_tx(*str++);
    }
}

/** Send progmem string over UART */
void uart_puts_pgm(const char* str)
{
    char c;
    while (0 != (c = pgm_read_byte(&str))) {
        uart_tx(c);
        str++;
    }
}
```

The normal one works just fine, but the progmem one prints infinite stream of `0xFF`. Where is the mistake?

I've worked with progmem before, and it always worked.. I can't seem to find the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh, I shouldn't dereference the pointer there...

```
pgm_read_byte(&str)
```

should be just

```
pgm_read_byte(str)
```

It's working now.